# How to make RecyclerView inside drawer?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-drawer

I'm new in Android.
I have large amount of records on server and I want to show them in android app. I think about make drawer with recycle view inside and load hundreds of records to `RecyclerView`.

1) Is it correct way to show such amount of records in drawer -> `RecyclerView`

2) how to create drawer with `RecyclerView` inside?

Answer (score 0):

You should not put `RecyclerView` inside drawer.

Comment: Why I should not put `RecyclerView` in drawer?

Comment: Becasue the point of using `RecyclerView` is when You have a lot of items and adding them all at once could significantly decrase your App performance or scrolling list could take too much resources. That is what `RecyclerView` is for, it prevents from creating a huge amount of View/Object, instead it is recycling them. Inside Drawer you should put items which are previously declared. Drawer is not meant to be used with huge lists, it is bad practice to do. If You really have a lot of items/options which You would like to implement, You should use different view/solution to do it